# Weblogic 12c and Java EE 7 Features

Tags: java, weblogic, java-ee-7, weblogic12c

As we know, WebLogic Server 12c supports natively Java EE 7.

However, if we take a look at the [WebLogic 12c documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/NOTES/index.html#CJAFAHGI) of standards there will be a lot of versions differences. Such as:

Java EE 7: Servlet 3.1, JPA 2.1, EL 3.0, JAX-RS 2.0, EJB 3.2, JMS 2.0

WLS 12c: Servlet 3.0, JPA 2.0, EL 2.2, JAX-RS 1.1, EJB 3.1, JMS 1.1

It's just a matter of importing the libraries? Or there is any restriction to use these latest versions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: WebLogic 12c is JEE 6 compliant. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24494/toc.htm

Comment: Weblogic Middleware 12c (12.2.1.0.0) is finally released with Java EE7...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

** UPDATE: WebLogic 12.2.1 is now released. It is Java EE 7 and JDK 8 certified. **

Wrong! **WebLogic 12c (12.1.3) is Java EE 6 certified.**

Versions 12.1.1 and 12.1.2 do not offer any feature of Java EE 7, although it is possible to run some new APIs over them (but you won't get support). But as you are interested, it provided on release WebLogic 12.1.3 a few Web-related features of Java EE 7 (such as fully compliant JAX-RS 2.0 and WebSockets).

Please read through [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24494/toc.htm#CJAFGHFG) as pointed by **David Hunt**. For a roadmap of WebLogic 12.1.3, you can see the blog post [The road ahead for WebLogic 12c 12.1.3 and 12.1.4 (12.2.1)](https://blogs.oracle.com/emeapartnerweblogic/entry/the_road_ahead_for_weblogic2).

Answer (score 6):

Weblogic 12c 12.2.1 fully supports Java EE 7. [Finally released...](https://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/exciting_news_prime_content_from)

Weblogic 12c 12.1.3 supports some of Java EE 7.

Comment: when will 12.1.4 be out?

Comment: websphere java ee 7 is out, glassfish with java ee7 was out in 2013 i think, shame on you weblogic team