# Weblogic 12.1.2 with JPA 2.1

Tags: java, spring, jpa, weblogic

I am trying to use SpringJPA 1.10.1 which provides support for JPA 2.1 and StoredProcedureQuery class to execute procedure.
But whenever I execute the procedure, I am getting following exception:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/persistence/StoredProcedureQuery

I have checked other questions link but all are referring to weblogic 12.1.3. 
Is there any way to enable JPA 2.1 with weblogic 12.1.2?

Comment: This seems to be related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24029543/2580773

Comment: yes, but It doesn't say anything about using JPA 2.1 with Weblogic 12.1.2. Does Weblogic 12.1.2 not support JPA 2.1?

Comment: It says: `12.1.2 do not offer any feature of Java EE 7`.  For JPA2.1 you need Java EE7